# Not able to disable port 1099

Tags: java, activemq-classic, rmi, jmx

From last few days we are observing that in our all services, port `1099` is open and rmiregistry is listening to that port. But we were not able to figure out why RMI registry is listening to that port. Later, after doing some analysis, I found out that there is a internal ActiveMQ broker which is responsible for opening that port. I believe our application service connects to ActiveMQ through RMI connector and for that reason `1099` port was open. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Ref : [Spring Boot 2 application cannot overwrite RMIRegistry default port 1099 to make JMX connections safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640776/spring-boot-2-application-cannot-overwrite-rmiregistry-default-port-1099-to-make)

To overwrite this default feature I am forcing Tomcat to make rmiregistry listen to the port which I want:

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12345"
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=12345"
```

But, this change didn't help. rmiregistry was still listening to port `1099`. I verified that by running `lsof -i:1099` command.
It stopped listening to that port only after doing below change

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dorg.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.createConnector=false"
```

But this change will disable the internal broker also if I am not wrong.

Could you please let me know , what else I need to do so that rmiregistry listen to port `12345` and ActiveMQ broker also
works without any issue. Do I need to make any change in ActiveMQ configuration?

Comment: You say, "I believe our application service connects to ActiveMQ through RMI connector and for that reason `1099` port was open. Please correct me if I am wrong." But how can anybody on Stack Overflow how your application service connects to ActiveMQ? Also, if your application service *is* using `1099` then won't disabling it break your application service?

Comment: Does your activemq.xml contain a managementContext setting?

Comment: First question here is why? Why do you prefer port 12345 over port 1099? They're only numbers.